# Electromagnet and MOSFETS

Tags: microcontroller

so currently I am trying to achieve a working electromagnet that will be powered by an AVR microcontroller and will be turned on and of when metal is sensed. Currently I have LED reflecting and sensing the block which passing through the photo diode and tells the AVR when to turn on the electromagnet. My problem is with the electromagnet. I have made my own and currently I need to put 9V through it with 0.5Amps. Now I know I cna use a mosfet as a switch to turn it on and off however I am not sure how to work out the values for the resistors in the circuit. I will be using a similar circuit to the one shown on this page http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/77.php. However I am unsure how to develope the resistor values I would need to ensure my magnet works correctly. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The circuit in your link will work with almost any resistor values, and none of them depend on the electormanget you have.

As the text says, R1 should be between 100 ohm and 1 kiloohm. Check your parts drawer -- any resistor in this range will work. If you do not care, put a 100 ohm resistor. The exact value does not matter unless you are going to turn your magnet on and off very frequently.

R2 is a pull-down resistor. The pull down resistor value depend on the CPU, and is usually in the 1K to 100K range. I like to use 4.7k resistors because I have a big box of them.

As a reminder, make sure your MOSFET is sensitive enough for your microcontroller (this means you need "logic level gate").